# Programmatically setting grid sort

Tags: sorting, datasource, kendo-ui

Is it possible to programmatically set the sort parameter of a KendoUI DataSource before reading data and avoiding a second server reading?
The scope is setting a default sort on a certain user interaction. How?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, because the answers are not getting to the point (or maybe I am not understanding how things work).

I define a Kendo DataSource with an initial sort:

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    parameterMap: function (inputParams, operation) {
        return JSON.stringify(inputParams)
    },
    // default sort
    sort: [
        {field: "field_1", dir: "asc"},
        {field: "field_2", dir: "asc"}
    ]
});
```

This DataSource is bound to a Kendo grid:

```
var grid = $("element").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: datasource   
});
```

Then I have a button that calls a "read" on the DataSource and populates the grid with the first page of data:

```
$("#btn").bind("click", function(e) {
    datasource.page(1);
});
```

This way, after clicking the button, the user gets data ordered by "field_1" and "field_2", and the grid shows this sort on column headers. The user then could reorder the data in any way, by clicking on column header.

What I would like to do is to reset the default sort to the initial one, as defined in the DataSource declaration, showing it again on column headers, and without create a new DataSource again.

Something like:

```
$("#btn").bind("click", function(e) {
    datasource.sort = [
        {field: "field_1", dir: "asc"},
        {field: "field_2", dir: "asc"}
    ]; 
    datasource.page(1);
});
```

The solutions provided do not seem to reach the point (and still I do not understand why I am losing reputation points for a legitimate question that seems to be not so trivial and should be addressed by the framework).

Please show me I am wrong (I am not worrying about losing reputation - I would like to just understand how to solve a problem).

Comment: I should suppose it is not possible.

Comment: it seems to work in JS by doing                     $grid.dataSource.sort(
                        { field: "A", dir: "desc" },
                        { field: "B", dir: "asc" },
                        { field: "C", dir: "asc" },
                        { field: "D", dir: "desc" }
                    ); The only problem I see though is that the sort indicators don't show up on all the columns,

Answer (score 30):

```
var kendoGrid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
var dsSort = [];
dsSort.push({ field: "fieldName1", dir: "asc" });
dsSort.push({ field: "fieldName2", dir: "desc" });
kendoGrid.dataSource.sort(dsSort);
```

Comment: is it possible to update the actual grid.dataSource.data() sorting? not just the view

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jsfiddle for exactly what you are asking: http://jsfiddle.net/MechStar/c2S5d/

In a nutshell though, you need to set the dataSource to null initially, then inject the dataSource when you get the needed input from the user:

myKendoGrid.data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(getKendoDataSource("ShipName", "asc"));

```
var getKendoDataSource = function (sidx, sord) {
  return new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
      read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    sort: {
      field: sidx ? sidx : "",
      dir: sord ? sord : ""
    }
  });
};
var myKendoGrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "OrderID" },
    { field: "ShipName" },
    { field: "ShipCity" }
  ],
  dataSource: null,
  pageable: {
    pageSizes: [10, 20, 50, 100, 200]
  },
  resizable: true,
  scrollable: false,
  sortable: {
    allowUnsort: false
  }
});
$("#link").click(function () {
  myKendoGrid.data("kendoGrid")
    .setDataSource(getKendoDataSource("ShipName", "asc"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible via the [sort](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#sort-array--objectdefault) setting.

Comment: Not actually, the sort invoke a second call to the server. I would like to change sort before reading data, modifying the default sort.

Comment: Sigh ... Did you really try it? Perhaps you are using the sort method instead of the sort configuration option.

Comment: I tried both. Could you provide an example? Please refer to the comment I left to the other answer to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then use the parameterMap function. It is called every time a request is made. Find more info in the docs: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportparametermap-function

Answer (score 1):

So you want to set the sort before it reads data the first time ?  Just make sure you have autobind: false on your ui control, then set the sort properties on the datasource, and then call datasource.read() when you are ready to get the sorted data.

Comment: Ok, but if I wanna set sort after, outside the datasource declaration, just before each read call, because the sort condition change or just to reset to adefault value? It seems to me the only way of achieving it is to destroy the existing datasource, creating a new one with the new sort parameter.

Comment: You can do that.  var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({});  myDataSource.sort = [{field: "myFieldName", dir: "asc"}, {field: "myOtherField", dir: "desc"}]; Then call myDataSource.read();

Answer (score 1):

I know what you are trying achieve. I had to do the same because we are saving the user sorting and filtering (client side in my case) and we cannot use grid functions *getOptions/setOptions* for other reasons.
Even if you set **autobind:false** this is not going to work as you expect, if you see the definition for autobind:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-autoBind

*If set to false the widget will not bind to the data source during initialization. In this case data binding will occur when the change event of the data source is fired. By default the widget will bind to the data source specified in the configuration.*

When you do a **dataSource.sort()**, this fires a **change** event, then, a **read** is done in the dataSource implicitly (that's why you have a second server reading).

So, what you have to do is create a new dataSource with the required sort options and then call a **dataSource.read()** explicitly.

For example (you can extend your default options to not repeat configuration):

```
var options = $.extend({}, dataSourceOptions);
options.sort = [
        {field: "field_1", dir: "asc"},
        {field: "field_2", dir: "asc"}
    ];
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(options);
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
grid.dataSource.read();
```

Hope this help.
Regards!