# Sorting Grid data in kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to sort the retrieved data wrt to description field but sorting is not working on it.

UI Code: Displays the data correctly

```
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autoSync: true,
    data: transformation.Activities,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "TransformerActivityUID",
            fields: {

                //It has different field. for instance one is  
                TargetTable: { editable: false, sortable: true },

            }
        }
    }, 
    sort: { field: "Description", dir: "desc" },
    group: { field: "TargetTable" } 
});

CreateGrid("functionTable", new BasicGrid(gridDataSource, columns, ActivityChanged));
ChangesDetection(ToggleSave);
AutoResizeModal("95%");
var grid = GetGridData("functionTable");
$("#functionsList").kendoDropTarget({
    group: "gridGroup",
    drop: AddActivity
});

grid.table.kendoDropTarget({
    group: "gridGroup",
    drop: AddActivity
});
```

When I retrieve the data I want it to be sorted by description field

```
functionTableGrid = GetGridData("functionTable");
gridSource = functionTableGrid.dataSource;
gridData = functionTableGrid.dataSource.data(); 
var dsSort = [];
dsSort.push({ field: "Description", dir: "desc" });
var testData = gridSource.sort(dsSort);
var sortedData= testdata.data();
//I have tried this 
gridData.dataSource.sort(dsSort) //not working
gridSource.sort(dsSort); // not working
```

Its important that I have the same data here as it is shown in UI. 
I have tried different things but I am not sure how it will work. I am quite new to JavaScript so any help would be great.

Comment: Does this link help? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863111/kendoui-programmatically-setting-grid-sort

Comment: var kendoGrid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid'); actually I dont understand this line.

Comment: I have seen this question but its not working for me

Comment: var kendoGrid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid'); just return the kendo grid object for the element #grid

Comment: element.data('kendoGrid'); <--- Returns an instance to a grid previously instantiated.  element.kendoWindow({...}) creates an instance.  You can also create an return in one statement. --> var x=element.kendoWindow({...}).data('kendoGrid');

Comment: var kendoGrid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid'); I have replace it by var kendoGrid = $("#grid").data('functionTable'); it returns null. Actually its not my code I am just removing the error. So I am not sure where I can find #grid and kendoGrid

Comment: Please update your code to show us how and when your grid is initialized.  For now we only see a dataSource object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert your data array (gridData in your case) to json array by calling `gridData.toJson()` to it. and try something like:

```
gridData = [{name: "tester 03", param2: "test3"},
            {name: "tester 01", param2: "test1"},
            {name: "tester 02", param2: "test2"}]; //Assuming some test values here

var sortedData  = a.sort(function(e,f) {
    return e.name < f.name; //by name or description or whatever
});
```

Or convert it to a function if this dir thing is about the direction of sort

```
function sortData(arr, sorter) {
    return arr.sort(function(e,f) {
            return sorter.dir == "desc" ?
                    e[sorter.field] < f[sorter.field] : e[sorter.field] > f[sorter.field];
    });
}
```

And pass the values like: `sortData(gridData, {field: "Description", dir: "desc"})`

Hope it works.